# Horizontal Align Images inside DIV

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align Images horizontally inside a DIV, but its not working.

Here is my code:

`HTML:`

```
<div id="HeaderImages">
    <img src="Images/1_home_main.png" width="32%" />
    <img src="Images/1_structure_home.png" />
    <img src="Images/2_insurance_home.png" />
    <img src="Images/3_credit_home.png" />
    <img src="Images/4_actions_home.png" />
</div>
```

`CSS:`

```
#HeaderImages
{
position: relative;
top: 120px;
right: 500px;
text-align:center;
}
#HeaderImages img
{
display:inline-block;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Make a Fiddle for this.

Comment: Make quick fiddle.net

Comment: @azeem Do you want really want to position the `<div>` tag with top and right adjustments?

Answer (score 1):

You are using relative position of `right` which prevents it from centering. Also, `margin: 0 auto;` will help you accomplish this.

```
#HeaderImages
{
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
top: 120px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Yes. And you can get rid of the img styles. Those are not needed.

Comment: Just noticed that, it's true.

Comment: `img` are by default `inline-block`... so that class itself is not required. `right` was the only problem with op's code.

Comment: I never knew that! Thanks.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer. here are the specs: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/img.html

Answer (score 0):

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6hsjkz5d/)

remove `position:relative` in

```
#HeaderImages
{

top: 120px;
right: 500px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: positioning has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/pnxm4adn/2/

the images act as `display:inline-block;` to fix the spacing issue set the parent `font-size:0;` this will remove the whitespace between images

removed your `position:relative` and its values of `#HeaderImages` so that the images are visible

```
#HeaderImages {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:0;
}
```

Comment: that's what i answered early

Answer (score 0):

You are giving width to only first element of div, so other all elements that is img taking the width as per image size, but width is not enough so remaining img position is below the first line. So my suggestion is give the remaining width/4 to each remaining img tag

```
img{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 16%;
}
```

```css
img{
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 16%;
}

   

    #HeaderImages
     {
     position: relative;
     top: 20px;

    text-align:center;
    }

    #HeaderImages img
    {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:16%;
      border:1px solid green;
      box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    #HeaderImages img:first-child{
     width:32%;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="HeaderImages">
        <img src="bg_black.png"/>
        <img src="bg_black.png" />
        <img src="bg_black.png"/>
        <img src="bg_black.png" />
        <img src="bg_black.png" />
      </div>

   

}
```